# Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: "no required module provides package github.com/block/go: go.mod ile not found"

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I got this error while running hyperledger fabric project "Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg error starting container: error starting container: Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 1 "no required module provides package github.com/block/go: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory; see 'go help modules'"
I've tried different solutions but still this error is not resolved

I am trying to run chaincode by this error occurs

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.